# How can i modify this nested for loop in C#?

Tags: c#, series, pascals-triangle

I am trying to print out a pyramid/Pascal Triangle that will give output in series of 3. You can see it in the example below.

```
                               1
                           1   3   1
                       1   3   9   3   1
                   1   3   9   27  9   3   1
               1   3   9   27  81  27  9   3   1
           1   3   9   27  81  243 81  27  9   3  1
      1    3   9   27   81  243 729 243 81  27  9  3  1
  1   3   9   27  81   243 729 2187 729 243 81 27  9  3   1
```

Instead of getting the above output, I am getting this:

[image: code output]

Here is my code:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class PiscalTriangle
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter length : ");
            int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
            {
                for (int j = num; j > i; j--)
                {
                    Console.Write("  ");
                }
                int val = 1;
                for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(val + "   ");
                    val = val * (i - j) / (j + 1);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're oututting a normal Pascal triangle. Do you have any documentation on the "series 3" one?

Comment: Not exactly, the actual problem is to write a nested for loop that prints the output for which i show in my question.

Comment: Can you explain more about you're desired output? - is it just columns multiplied by 3 in vertical downward direction + horizontal 3 -> 1 left and right?

Comment: This is the output that i want                                           
                                                      1
                                                 1   3   1
                                            1   3   9   3   1
                                      1   3   9   27  9   3   1
                                 1   3   9   27  81  27  9   3   1
                          1   3   9   27  81  243 81  27  9   3  1
                  1    3   9   27   81  243 729 243 81  27  9  3  1
          1   3   9   27  81   243 729 2187 729 243 81 27  9  3   1

Comment: each drop down row should be multiple by 3 and in a pascal format

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are three main aspects to be considered for generating the desired ouput:

- The depth of the pascal tree which is defined with the help of `num` variable and an iterator `i` which ranges from `1 to num`
- The elements in each row of the pascal tree are in the sequence 1,3,5,7.. which when correlated with depth of tree is equivalent to `2i-1`. Hence the row values iterator `j` ranges from `1 to 2i-1`
- And finally the value `(For example 3rd row, 1 3 9 3 1)`, can be written in the form of 3 power x, where x increases from `0` to `i` and then decreases to `0`

By summing up the 3 conditions, we can get our desired output.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class PiscalTriangle
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter length : ");
            int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            
            for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
            {
                for (int j = num; j > i; j--)
                {
                    Console.Write("  ");
                }
                var x = 0;
                for (double j = 1; j <= 2*i-1; j++)
                {
                    double val = Math.Pow(3, x);
                    Console.Write(val + " ");
                    if(j < i)
                    {
                        x++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        x--;
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of which changes you performed. Code-only answers are not good answers.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen updated answer by adding in context to the code written.